# Padé approximation of a complex function

Tags: interpolation, complex, approximation

I have an interesting problem for the Mathematica. I have some function, let's call it $G$. This is function of discrete set of equidistant points on imaginary axis, $i \omega_n$, so the typical data looks like:

```
    G = {{-3.11018, 0.0004195}, {-3.04734, 0.000451273}, {-2.98451, 0.000486051},
{-2.92168, 0.000524223}, {-2.85885, 0.000566223}, {-2.79602, 0.000612542}, 
{-2.73319, 0.000663741}, {-2.67035, 0.000720457}, ...};
```

where the first number is imaginary part of $\omega_n$ (real part is automatically zero, because we are on the imaginary axis).

I want to take this function of discrete set of points, do something with it and get a function of continuous variable on the real axis, $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$. I know for sure, that this function's asymptotical behaviour for $\left| \omega \right| \to \infty$ is $\propto 1/\left| \omega \right|$. The 'something' I want to do with it is the Pade approximation and because I know the asymptotical behaviour, I can tune the power of numerator and denominator:

$$G_n = \frac{p_0 + p_1 i \omega_n + p_2 (i \omega_n)^2 + \cdots + p_{l-1} (i \omega_n)^{l-1}}{q_0 + q_1 i \omega_n + q_2 (i \omega_n)^2 + \cdots + q_{l-1} (i \omega_n)^{l-1} + q_l (i \omega_n)^l}$$

If I take $n$ to be some $2l+1$ values which I have my data for, I can solve this problem and leave no free parameters. Then I can take this function:

$$G (z) = \frac{p_0 + p_1 z + p_2 z^2 + \cdots + p_{l-1} z^{l-1}}{q_0 + q_1 z + q_2 z^2 + \cdots + q_{l-1} z^{l-1} + q_l z^l}$$

and of course restore the original function $G_n$ by setting $z = i \omega_n$, or to finally have my wanted function $G (\omega)$ by setting $z = \omega$.

I wanted to do as much as possible with built-in functions. Firstly, I noticed that PadeApproximant[function[x], {x,0,{l-1,l}}] takes only functions as an argument, like sin(x) or x^2 e^(-x). So I took my data set and interpolated it:

```
interG = Interpolation[G];
```

Then I tried the Pade approximation:

```
p = PadeApproximant[interG[x], {x, 0, {l-1, l}}];
```

Where I tried this for various $l$, e.g. 2, 5, 10, 50...

Either way, the result is FAR AWAY from what my data set G looks like! Even if this was a good approximation, I still have a problem to explain to Mathematica that the approximation is to be done on the imaginary axis (so the argument of the interpolation function has to be imaginary). The reason for discrepancy of Pade approximation and the original data set is perhaps the interpolation function: it approximates data set on some interval, but outside that interval, the interpolation function blows up to plus or minus infinity, so that might be the core of the problem. How can I solve those two problems? I thought that perhaps I can use some of Mathematica's built in functions, this approximation is really only about solving linear equations. Can you help me please? Thank you. If you want to play with some data set, use:

```
{{-3.11018, 0.0004195}, {-3.04734, 0.000451273}, {-2.98451, 
  0.000486051}, {-2.92168, 0.000524223}, {-2.85885, 
  0.000566223}, {-2.79602, 0.000612542}, {-2.73319, 
  0.000663741}, {-2.67035, 0.000720457}, {-2.60752, 
  0.00078342}, {-2.54469, 0.000853473}, {-2.48186, 
  0.000931585}, {-2.41903, 0.00101888}, {-2.35619, 
  0.00111667}, {-2.29336, 0.00122647}, {-2.23053, 
  0.00135006}, {-2.1677, 0.00148955}, {-2.10487, 
  0.00164741}, {-2.04204, 0.00182655}, {-1.9792, 
  0.00203045}, {-1.91637, 0.00226326}, {-1.85354, 
  0.00252996}, {-1.79071, 0.00283652}, {-1.72788, 
  0.00319022}, {-1.66504, 0.00359986}, {-1.60221, 
  0.00407627}, {-1.53938, 0.00463276}, {-1.47655, 
  0.00528582}, {-1.41372, 0.00605609}, {-1.35088, 
  0.00696952}, {-1.28805, 0.00805906}, {-1.22522, 
  0.00936695}, {-1.16239, 0.0109479}, {-1.09956, 
  0.0128734}, {-1.03673, 0.0152386}, {-0.973894, 
  0.0181713}, {-0.911062, 0.0218463}, {-0.84823, 
  0.0265074}, {-0.785398, 0.0325014}, {-0.722566, 
  0.0403345}, {-0.659734, 0.0507674}, {-0.596903, 
  0.064983}, {-0.534071, 0.0848997}, {-0.471239, 
  0.113791}, {-0.408407, 0.157613}, {-0.345575, 0.228129}, {-0.282743,
   0.351254}, {-0.219911, 0.59353}, {-0.15708, 1.17002}, {-0.0942478, 
  3.10261}, {-0.0314159, 15.9113}, {0.0314159, 15.9113}, {0.0942478, 
  3.10261}, {0.15708, 1.17002}, {0.219911, 0.59353}, {0.282743, 
  0.351254}, {0.345575, 0.228129}, {0.408407, 0.157613}, {0.471239, 
  0.113791}, {0.534071, 0.0848997}, {0.596903, 0.064983}, {0.659734, 
  0.0507674}, {0.722566, 0.0403345}, {0.785398, 0.0325014}, {0.84823, 
  0.0265074}, {0.911062, 0.0218463}, {0.973894, 0.0181713}, {1.03673, 
  0.0152386}, {1.09956, 0.0128734}, {1.16239, 0.0109479}, {1.22522, 
  0.00936695}, {1.28805, 0.00805906}, {1.35088, 0.00696952}, {1.41372,
   0.00605609}, {1.47655, 0.00528582}, {1.53938, 
  0.00463276}, {1.60221, 0.00407627}, {1.66504, 0.00359986}, {1.72788,
   0.00319022}, {1.79071, 0.00283652}, {1.85354, 
  0.00252996}, {1.91637, 0.00226326}, {1.9792, 0.00203045}, {2.04204, 
  0.00182655}, {2.10487, 0.00164741}, {2.1677, 0.00148955}, {2.23053, 
  0.00135006}, {2.29336, 0.00122647}, {2.35619, 0.00111667}, {2.41903,
   0.00101888}, {2.48186, 0.000931585}, {2.54469, 
  0.000853473}, {2.60752, 0.00078342}, {2.67035, 
  0.000720457}, {2.73319, 0.000663741}, {2.79602, 
  0.000612542}, {2.85885, 0.000566223}, {2.92168, 
  0.000524223}, {2.98451, 0.000486051}, {3.04734, 
  0.000451273}, {3.11018, 0.0004195}}
```

Comment: I think that the Pade approximation matches the derivatives of the function up to the specified order.  Unless you have a very high interpolation order, your approach is based on only a few points around zero.

Comment: Given the very rapid variation of the function around zero, I think it will be difficult to interpolate this function without additional assumptions (or more samples around zero).